# Find name of function in R using function body

Tags: r

In R you can use `match.fun` to find a function based on its name - can you do the opposite - if not why?

```
f1 <- function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
match.fun("f1")
function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

```
other_function(function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
# "f1"
```

Comment: There's not a 1 to 1 mapping between functions and names. Multiple names may point to the same function. Also, each function has it's own environment so it's possible that two functions might have the same "code" but are not the same because they have different environments (or closures). Plus not all functions need to have names, they can be anonymous.

Comment: Perhaps you can do `names(which(sapply(mget(lsf.str()), function(x) body(x) == body(function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))))))#
[1] "f1"`

Comment: How would that function work if I had `f1` and `f2 <- f1` but `f1` and `f2` are in different environments? Could you use recursion to find both function names? `e1 <- rlang::env(f1 = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
e2 <- rlang::env(f2 = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))`

Comment: How would this ever happen in the first place though? Are you assuming someone write down the exact same variable names and white space choices inside two different functions? Is `function(a, b) a+b` really different than `function(a,b) b+a` or `function(x, y) x+y`? What does it mean for two functions to be identical? What problem are you really trying to solve? And there's a difference between where the name that points to a function is defined and the environment attached to the function itself.

Comment: I think your answer that this isn't possible helped to clear up my mental model @MrFlick but after seeing the other answer supplied by Akrun I wanted to see how far that could be extended since it kind of contradicts what you were saying? I don't have a use case I'm just trying to clarify my mental model of functions in R

Comment: It looks what what's happening when you to `body(x)==body(y)` is that it's just deparsing the body into a string and comparing the values. So if you want to think of as two functions being equal if their deparsed body strings as the same, then that's technically possible but that may not be what you are after. It's just like searching for every variable that has the value of 5. It's possible but not efficient. I think the main point is that name->object is a one way (non-unique) look up in R.  There's no efficient way to go backwards. This is true for all values, not just functions.